# Cant show imagees from storage in laravel

Tags: laravel, storage

i am trying to show images which is stored in storage/app/public/directory and i am retreiving the image name with directory from database like 'projects/123456/jpg'. i have tried so many things but failed to show image..
i have tried this

```
<img id="before" src="<?php echo asset("storage/app/$data->pic_before_project"); ?>" height="100" 
  width="120">
```

and also this

```
<img id="before" src="{{ asset('/'.$data->pic_before_project) }}" height="100" width="120">
```

but those didnt work... here to mention i have already linked storage.
please help.

Comment: i had already mentioned in my question that i linked storage

Comment: is this in hosting or local there is two way to access public directory and both used in two ways\

Answer (score 0):

from this you can access folder wherever it saved

```
{{ URL::asset('/public/yourfolder/'.$data->pic_before_project) }}
```

or try this

```
{{ asset('yourfolder/'.$data->pic_before_project) }}
```

last code automatically access public folder when you are in localhost first one is using in hosting

Comment: it still didnt work. is there any permission factor or something. ? i am trying from localhost for now

Comment: Ahh can you show me what is output when you use this

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. just to share, the problem might occur when you are using an existing project where public/storage file is already linked. so deleteing the storage folder and then again linking the storage with php artisan storage:link command worked for me..